# How to uninstall dotnet 6?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-11

windows 11
windowsdesktop-runtime 6.0.9

The tool:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=windows
only lists up to 5.0 support, hasn't been updated in a year, and trying it `dotnet-core-uninstall list` doesn't list it, whereas `dotnet --info` does show a runtime installed.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I've found a silly sollution, which is to find and download the installer of the exact version I have and there will be an option to uninstall it, ffs Microsoft..